# Have trouble understanding some code in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS by following a book but I'm stuck at some lines of code which are hardly explained in the book.

So this selectCategory() function is included in the ng-click directive

```
<a ng-click="selectCategory()">Home</a>

<a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy:'category' | unique:'category'"
   ng-click="selectCategory(item)">

   {{item}}

</a>
```

and also here's the filter which is used to filter the listing products based on their categories when the ng-click directive is triggered

```
ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn">
```

those two are defined as follows:

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.controller("productListCtrl", function ($scope, $filter) {

    var selectedCategory = null;

    $scope.selectCategory = function (newCategory) {
        selectedCategory = newCategory;
    }

    $scope.categoryFilterFn = function (product) {
        return selectedCategory == null ||
        product.category == selectedCategory;
    }
});
```

I've already spent a lot of time trying to understand those code but I'm still pretty confused, especially about how the two functions are defined. Why $filter is also included in the argument? And also can you explain those definitions please, I'm really lost. Forgive me for being a newbie and many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really bad example !!

It should be :

```
<a ng-click="selectCategory()">Home</a>

<a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy:'category' | unique:'category'"
   ng-click="selectCategory(item.category)">

   {{item.category}}

</a>
```

So here you choose a category from the available categories (unique categories of products), then products that have this categories are listed (ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn>)

categoryFilterFn is a filter function, so products having category == selectedCategory are listed, and if no selectedCategory all products are listed :)

Hope this helps

Comment: and no need to inject $filter into this controller (no need to add it as an argument)

Comment: Hi, sorry about my late reply. The code in the example is actually correct. Correct me if I'm wrong, let me explain a bit and see now if I understand it right. 

$scope.data looks something like this,  
{
 products: [
 { name: "Product #1", description: "A product",
 category: "Category #1", price: 100 },
 {...},
 {...}]
}

so 'item' actually refers to the whole {} block, and because there's a 'unique' filter, item now only refers to the category.

Comment: When 'Home' Button is clicked, selectCategory() is triggered. Because no argument is passed, 'newCategory' is null so that 'selectedCategory' is also null, and this makes categoryFilterFn unable to filter anything so that products of all the categories will be listed at 'Home'.

But if 'item', which refers to one of the categories, is passed in the call, the variable 'selectedCategory' is not null anymore so that 'categoryFilterFn' can filter all the products of that category out.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and could you please also explain how 'return' works in this?`$scope.categoryFilterFn = function (product) {
  return selectedCategory == null ||
  product.category == selectedCategory;
 }` Does it return true or false? If it is, how does the filter know what to filter? Thanks!

Comment: if no selectedCategory selectedCategory == null --> true and the function return true for all products; otherwise (selectedCategory != null) if product.category == selectedCategory --> function returns true & if product.category =! selectedCategory --> function returns false

Comment: categoryFilterFn is a filter function so if it returns false the product is not displayed, if it return true the product is displayed